# query over one type in different entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

Here is a small extract of my domain model:

```
public class Chain
{
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public Chain Chain { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to create a query over `Product` in `Store` **and** the associated `Chain`. 
The question is how can I extend the query for the products that are stored in the belonging `Chain`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Store>()
    .Where(s => s.Id == searchCriteria.StoreId)
    .Select(s => s.Id);

Store storeAlias = null;
var query = _session.QueryOver<Product>()
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Stores, () => storeAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => storeAlias.Id).In(subQuery);
    //// some more clauses...
```

How can I do this? 
Please note: `Chain` property in `Store` could be `null`.

Comment: It would be *more* helpful if you could plain english definition of what you want to query instead of describing the QueryOver query.

Comment: Oke I tried to set the focus more to the concrete question. I hope my problem has become clearer now.

Comment: If you could specify an example of what the query is trying to do It would certainly help.

Comment: A very simple example is: Find all products for the store with given Id. As the result I get all products that are persisted directly in the store _AND_ in the associated chain. Do you see what I mean? The point is that I need to query for Product in distributed entities.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now..

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work. I did not try it on a local database but should put you in the right direction.

```
Product product = null;
Store store = null;
Chain chain = null;

//01. Load Products from Store

var productsFromStores 
     = QueryOver.Of(() => product)
             .JoinAlias(() => product.Stores, () => store)
             .Where(() => store.Id == searchCriteria.StoreId)
             .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id()));

//02.  If Chain DOES NOT refer Store 
  var productFromChains 
         = QueryOver.Of(() => store)
             .JoinAlias(() => store.Chain, () => chain)
             .JoinAlias(() => chain.Products, () => product)
             .Where(() => store.Id == StoreId)
             .Select(Projections.Distinct(
                     Projections.Property(() => product.Id)));

//03. Load Products from present either in the Store and or the chains
var products 
     = session.QueryOver(() => product)
       .Where(
             Restrictions.Or(
             Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => product.Id)
                                     .In(productsFromStores),
             Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => product.Id)
                                     .In(productFromChains)));
```

FYI : Please note that this may not be the most ideal way to handle your query. I always cringe when I look at use of `IN ()` and sub-queries.

If Chain DOES have a Store in it then //02 can be written as

```
//Load Products from Chains
//02.  If Chain DOES refer to a Store 
  var productFromChains 
         = QueryOver.Of(() => chain)
              .JoinAlias(() => chain.Store, () => store)
              .JoinAlias(() => chain.Products, () => product)
              .Where(() => store.Id == searchCriteria.StoreId)
              .Select(Projections.Distinct(
                           Projections.Property(() => product.Id)));
```

Comment: After some trials I have now the solution. I will posting it separatly. Thanks for pushing in the right direction!